# How to create and bind a context menu with array of markers on the Google map?

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps-markers

I am working on a treasure hunting project using JSP, Postgres and Tomcat.  After logging in, it should allow the admin to specify the map location, add various objects (like treasure and NPCs that are already saved in my database) to the map and be able to copy, paste and delete any objects.
Everything like login, and insert objects of various types, is working but now I want to enable a right-click context menu for each marker that will give the admin 3-4 options; copy, paste, delete, edit.

To achieve this, I have found the link very useful where the source code for the context menu is provided:  http://code.martinpearman.co.uk/googlemapsapi/contextmenu/1.0/src/ContextMenu.js

I created a ContextMenu.js file and copied the above code and then have the following function in my jsp file.  Please note that I'm retrieving a list of markers from my database as JSON object and looping through it to create and place the markers on the map.

```
function drawMap(){
            var markers = {};
            var contextMenu;

    var contextMenuOptions={};
    contextMenuOptions.classNames={menu:'context_menu', 
    menuSeparator:'context_menu_separator'};

    //  create an array of ContextMenuItem objects
    var menuItems=[];

    menuItems.push({id: "copy", className:'context_menu_item', 
    eventName:'copy_click', label:'Copy'});

    menuItems.push({id: "paste", className:'context_menu_item', 
    eventName:'paste_click', label:'Paste'});

    menuItems.push({id: "delete", className:'context_menu_item', 
    eventName:'delete_click', label:'Delete'});

    contextMenuOptions.menuItems=menuItems;

            lat='43.56873147104461';
            lng='-79.76628009520937';

            map = new google.maps.Map(
                    document.getElementById("map_container"), {
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                      zoom: 15,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });

json ='<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("data")%>'

                json = JSON.parse(json);


                for (i = 0; i <= json.length; i++) {
                    var lt,ln;

                    lat = json[i].latstr;
                    lng = json[i].lngstr;

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position:  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                        map: map
                    });
           contextMenu = new ContextMenu(map, contextMenuOptions); //stops at this point

           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick',function(e) {
           contextMenu.show(e.latLng);
                  });
        }  //end for loop

  google.maps.event.addListener(contextMenu, 'menu_item_selected', 
  function(object, latLng, eventName){
        //  latLng is the position of the ContextMenu
        //  eventName is the eventName defined for the clicked 
            ContextMenuItem in the ContextMenuOptions
            switch(eventName){
                case 'copy_click':
                    copyObject(object);
                    break;
                case 'paste_click':
                    pasteObject(object, latLng);
                    break;
                case 'delete_click':
                    deleteObject(object);
                    break;
            }
        });
}   //end function drawMap();
```

I am not sure where the problem is.  When I run the program, it just displays the first marker on the map and the right-click does nothing and I have tried `alert("hi");` to check the problem.  It stops at

```
contextMenu = new ContextMenu(map, contextMenuOptions);
```

I also tried to put an alert inside the `ContextMenu` function and it stops at the second line

```
this.setMap(map);
```

when I comment it out, it goes beyond this point, displays all the markers in the loop but the right-click does nothing.  which means that the `contextMenu.show(e.latLng);` is not working.  It may have something to do with the for loop.

Comment: Any errors on the console? Can you `try` `catch` the code to detect any problems?

Comment: Thanks for replying..........nope, no errors on the console.

Comment: Well, I would like to know what is the output of contextMenu. Can you try: `try{ contextMenu = new ContextMenu(map, contextMenuOptions); }catch(err) { console.log(err) }`

Comment: Also, try this: `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'contextmenu',function(e) {
           contextMenu.show(e.latLng);
                  });`

Comment: Apr 06, 2017 11:17:37 AM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: just the above error which i don't think has anything to do with this code, i tried both.  i replaced the ContextMenu with the first above line and it's just showing all the markers on the map but right-click does nothing

Comment: did you replace `rightclick` with `contextmenu`?

Comment: i replaced the contextMenu.show(e.latLng) with the one you provided and it does nothing too.....i also put an alert in the show function as follows:        ContextMenu.prototype.show=function(latLng, source){ //original
 alert("showing");
 this.source = source;
 if(!this.isVisible_){
  this.menu_.style.display='block';
  this.isVisible_=true;
 }
 this.position_=latLng;
 this.draw();
};

Comment: could it be that .show expects 2 arguments latLng and source? and i'm only passing e.latLng?  I also tried to do it without source but nothing happened.

Comment: no no sorry, i didn't realize.........let me try that now (replacing rightclick with contextmenu)

Comment: i replaced it........what should it do?

Comment: Try again! right click on the marker. it should display your contextmenu

Comment: Did it work this time?

Comment: the problem is that it stops at the second line in the function ContextMenu.  function ContextMenu(map, options){
 alert("context");
 options=options || {};
 
 this.setMap(map);  //stops here.......
 
 this.map_=map;
 this.mapDiv_=map.getDiv();  //original
 this.id = options.id;
 this.classNames_=options.classNames || {};
 
 this.menuItems_=options.menuItems || [];  //original
 this.pixelOffset=options.pixelOffset || new google.maps.Point(10, -5);
 this.zIndex = options.zIndex || null;
 
}

Comment: and returns null to the contextMenu

Comment: but when i comment that line //this.setMap(map) then the contextMenu has a value and displays [object object] in alert

Comment: That's another problem! Let me take a look!

Comment: Is it map object getting created! put a `console.log(map)`

Comment: the map object is getting created because it displays a map and puts the first marker on the map

Comment: I found this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jEhJ3/3409/ hope it could help you!

Comment: I've already tried that as well........anyway, THANKS alot for your time.